# Storing passwords in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter

Is there a way to store secrets/access secrets/passwords in notebooks? I have an api endpoint where I pull data from, and I dont want to expose the apiKey to everyone who can view the notebook.

Comment: You really need to encapsulate the API access as your own secured service.

Comment: Thanks Kenny...I ended up doing that...created an exe to read secret from the machine store, execute the privileged command, and return the output - and I call this exe from the notebook

Answer (score 13):

Store your credentials in a JSON or YAML, and have your notebook parse the necessary parts.

```
import json

with open('credentials.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']
```

You should avoid printing the secrets in the cell outputs, for otherwise any technique you choose will be foiled.

Comment: hmmm...that effectively hides it from plain view, but the problem is that person with access to the notebook can still get the secret. I'm guessing there is no way the person with notebook access can be blocked from accessing the secret...

Answer (score 13):

The simplest solution I've been using for a while.

Use [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) Portable password input module.

```
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass('Enter your password')

print('Your password is: ' + password)
```

Comment: This is super handy. Will be using this from now on.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's the only answer that can be used with a public notebook so that 1) the notebook can still run and 2) no one can view the API key.

Answer (score 11):

[cco's answer is good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44961139), but if you're looking for a simpler solution, many people use environmental variables to keep secrets segregated from source code.

For example, you can provide them when executing your script in the shell:

```
$ API_TOKEN=abc123 python script.py
```

In your source code:

```
import os
API_TOKEN = os.environ.get("API_TOKEN")
```

For your Jupyter notebooks, you can use [`python-dotenv`](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) or a similar package to "retrieve" a `.env` file that contains your project's secrets and is ignored by your version control system.

Once you've created your `.env` file (either manually, or using [the package's command line tool](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv#command-line-interface)), you can use `python-dotenv` in Jupyter (or IPython) like so:

```
%load_ext dotenv
%dotenv
import os
os.environ.get("API_TOKEN")
```

Comment: is there any way the person with notebook access can be blocked from accessing the secret?

Comment: @sargeMonkey The secret would be supplied at the command line or in the `.env` file. If it's in the `.env file, you simply wouldn't give this file to anyone else.

Comment: yes, but the person with notebook access can access the secret by simply doing a os.environ.get("API_TOKEN"), right?

Comment: @sargeMonkey No. The function retrieves the environment values. Without the environment, the function will return 'None'.

Comment: right, but the env vars should be available for the notebook to run, and if it runs, the user can print out the secret. Other than making some REST api to return the data without revealing the secret, I dont see another way to keep the secret away from the user.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [keyring](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring) package to store sensitive information in a system-specific protected store.
It can be installed via `pip` from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring).

Comment: is there any way the person with notebook access can be blocked from accessing the secret?

Comment: Not that I can think of.  If the script (notebook) has access to the secret to authenticate, the notebook user can use the same method to look at the secret.

Answer (score 0):

Use standart configparser and settings.ini file without additional dependency.

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('settings.ini')

API_KEY = config['DEFAULT']['API_KEY']
```